# Defining macros for a source file form the command line

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to define a macro for the source file from the command line on an ubuntu system using the -D flag .
The source file is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int n){
    if(n!=1){
    return(n * factorial(n-1));
    }
    else return 1;
    #ifdef DEEPAK

    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    #endif
}
int main()
{
    factorial(4);
    return(0);
}
```

The command I am typing is:

```
gcc -Wall -DDEEPAK  factorial.cpp -o main
```

BUT, I am getting the error:

```
/tmp/cc4Ii5l2.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
factorial.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
factorial.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you should use g++ not gcc . and your cout is useless here.

Comment: Invoke g++ instead of gcc, by default gcc is not linking c++ standard library hence the unresolved reference to std::cout. The macro is defined just right.

Comment: Thanks  a lot . Alas, A very silly mistake.

Comment: You should compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `g++` instead of `gcc` in the command, because `gcc` doesn't link to the C++ STL by default, and hence it gives an undefined reference to `std::ios_base`.

```
g++ -Wall -DDEEPAK  factorial.cpp -o main
```